# Sharepoint 2010 ModalDialog title

Tags: development, javascript

I am creating a popup window in sharepoint using this code in javascript.

```
function openDialog(title, url, width, height, CallResult) {
    var options = { url: getUrl(url),
        title: title,
        allowMaximize: true,
        showClose: true,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: CallResult
    };
    ModalDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    return ModalDialog;
}
```

I want to know if anyone has an idea on how to change the title of the Modal Dialog dynamically when it is open.

For example when the popup opens the title is "my title" and when i press a button in the page that is contained in the popup the title changes.

Can it be done?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with simple js:

```
SP.UI.UIUtility.setInnerText(parent.document.getElementById("dialogTitleSpan"), "hello");
```

This code was tested and works for me.

Comment: I am getting document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: I've updated the answer. This code works for me, but I've tested it only from IE developer window.

Comment: Do i need to do a postback so the change can be visible?

Comment: *Do i need to do a postback* - no, it's a client-side action, it'll be performed immediately.

Comment: I need to change the title from the page that is inside the popup

Comment: I've updated the answer again :)) tested it finally, simply you should use parent.document.getElementById...

Comment: Andrey it right, but use it inside setTimeout with 1 second delay. (tested din IE 11 and chrome)

Answer (score 0):

The modal dialog is nothing more than a chromeless javascript window; while I haven't done it, I'd imagine you could use jQuery to sniff out the header bar of the modal dialog and render different text into it.

After loading jQuery you could do something like:

```
$("div.classofmodalheader").html('New Title');
```

I'd have to test it, but I'd imagine it'd work. You'd need to crack open some dev tools and explore the DOM of the modal window to figure out what that tag and class need to be.

**Edit**:

Since Omlin posted the actual ID for the element, here's some revised jQuery (to his point, you can also do it with straight Javascript).

```
$("#dialogTitleSpan").html('New Title');
```