# Sharepoint 2010 MdalDialog title

Tags: development, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharepoint 2010 ModalDialog title](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13087/sharepoint-2010-modaldialog-title)

Hi,

I am creating a popup window in sharepoint using this code in javascript.

```
function openAutoResizableDialog(title, url, CallResult) {
    var options = { url: getUrl(url),
        title: title,
        allowMaximize: true,
        showClose: true,
        autoSize: true,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: CallResult
    };
    ModalDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    return ModalDialog;
}
```

I want to know if anyone has an idea on how to change the title of the Modal Dialog dynamically when it is open.

For example when the popup opens the title is "my title" and when i press a button in the page that is contained in the popup the title changes.

Can it be done?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing. It worked perfectly.

```
SP.UI.UIUtility.setInnerText(parent.document.getElementByI("dialogTitleSpan"), "hello");

Or:

parent.document.getElementById("dialogTitleSpan").innerHTML = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done. It's just HTML isn't it?

### When using jQuery

```
$("#dialogTitleSpan").text("Some other title.");
```

### Javascript only solution

```
document.getElementById("dialogTitleSpan").innerHTML = "Some other title";
```